# How to limit express api access?

Tags: javascript, api, express

I am looking for general idea on how to limit access to the api. I have authentication implemented and some resources are locked to authenticated users. But how do i make authorization and grant specific app permissions, so each user in that app can have different permissions?

i.e.

```
app.get('/users', (req, res) => {
 var permissions = {'users_read'};
 if(permissions.indexof('token_flags')!=-1){
 ...} else{return false}
});
```

or

```
app.post('/users', permissions('users_read'), ()=>{
 ...
});
```

user1: `users_read`

user2: `users_read`, `users_execute`

user3: `settings_read`

admin1: `access_all`
//user 1&2 and admin will get api resonse, user3 not

Comment: "the api"? Which API?

Comment: @Liam restful api in express

Answer (score 0):

you can store your pages into a object as index or key then just set the autorized users type as value in an array way

```
var user_type = 1; // 1: user, 2: staff, 3: admin

var permissions = {
    'users_read': [1, 2, 3],
    'users_execute': [2, 3],
    'settings_read': [3]
};


app.get('/users', (req, res) => {
    var page = 'users_read';
    if(permissions[page].indexOf(user_type) != -1){
        // autorized
    } else{
        return false
    }
});
```